# jquery maphilight plugin - how to keep black colors of image 100% black when hilighted

Tags: jquery, canvas, maps, opacity, area

I'm using jquery.maphilight plugin to hilight some parts of the image. My image is transparent png containing wireframe:

[wireframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb0mt.jpg)

As you can see, there is an higlighted semitransparent area (html canvas element generated by the plugin, that is overlaying a wireframe. Problem is, that this semitransparent color is taking out the 100% black color of wireframe lines.

Is there any hack that could fix it? Possible solution could be to set a blend mode of that area somehow, or place generated canvas elemets behind the png image, or setting z-indexes of elements. However I am unsucessful with all the listed ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the canvas element function as an overlay element you won't be able to use the context blending mode such as `multiply`.

Luckily though, you can use this in CSS as well through `mix-blend`. You have to obtain the canvas element the plugin is using, then apply this CSS rule to it:

```
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

Note: It's not supported in [all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend) (FF/Chrome OK).

**Result:**

[image: result image]

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle ="rgba(255,200,0,0.6)";
ctx.fillRect(50, 10, 180, 100);
```

```css
body {position:relative}
#c, img {position:absolute;left:0;top:0}
img {width:300px;height:auto}
#c {
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/BhOHHWT.png"><canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily overwrite default color change on select using:

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

i normally use this for text highlighting on selection.
*In your case, use it on image or whatever that prints your black lines instead of changing background.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with highlighting map areas, or?

Comment: i never used maphighlight plugin, so i cannot answer if it has not to do. But  i'm convinced that it is not changing black opacity, so it have to overlay with a "yellow" layer over everything. You can try to change this yellow to a subtle color and with less opacity. This will change minimum the colors that are behind